# Create custom field(checkboxes) for product form on admin

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml

I want to add custom checkboxes to the product form on admin. I tried using the following code:

```
<htmlContent name="typeofstore" sortOrder="2">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Type Of store</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <wrapper>
            <canShow>true</canShow>
            <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
        </wrapper>
    </settings>
    <block name="typeofstore" class="Forms\Registration\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Store" template="Forms_Registration::product/typeofstore.phtml"/>
</htmlContent>
```

but the issue is that I want to add the custom data to the product tables of magento so that I can export the custom fields to the CSV file.
I also tried using the checkbox set but that does not work, the page kept loading for ages,

**Updated here**

thanks Jigs. your answer helped me to get closer to what i want.
one question, how to separate the labels and values, for example,
I want to add multiselect and lables would be label 1, label 2 with values 1,2 respectively,
Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can create **product attribute** and assign it to **attribute set**

no need to create any other file